# Magento2 adds products to random category

Tags: magento2, category

I have weird issue in Magento2

I sent a request via SOAP. And I have category id in this request.

**Steps:**

1. Save product.
2. Delete product categories
3. Add new category/categories

After that I see different categories in the product.

Product has correct category and also wrong other category.

How it possible?

Thanks.

Comment: Double-check that the category assignments for the product are being saved correctly and that there are no conflicting records in the database that could cause unexpected behavior.

Comment: Thanks @Harun, I answered below.

Answer (score 0):

@Harun

Thanks for your reply. I checked few days and I couldn't see anything. Because I am using database query for delete and add categories.

```
DELETE FROM `catalog_category_product` WHERE `product_id` = {$productId}

INSERT INTO `catalog_category_product` (`category_id`, `product_id`) VALUES ('{$category}', '{$productId}')
```

Can it be related indexers or something?

Also I cannot use categoryLinkManagement because it has bug for multiple webshop. It cannot delete categories in product.

Comment: it could be related to indexers